# Webpart randomly stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, custom-web-parts

We have a webpart running on SharePoint 2010 that displays our latest news that has been in use for at least 3 years. As of yesterday, it stopped working. It displays the webpart with title and the button linked to the news list works, but it does not show a preview of the news item, scroll, or have buttons to move between different news items. There is also an error displayed below it:

[Control] An exception has occurred.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Nothing has been modified on this page, in the list, nor have the webparts been changed. Googling doesn't get me too far either. I did see people relating that to low disk space, which we were encountering and has been taken care of but still this webpart just won't work!

[image]

Comment: if there is disk issue then did you reset IIS on all servers after fixing that.

Comment: We did reboot all servers associated with SP.

Comment: Did you checked the ULS logs, may be you need to enable the verbose logging.

Comment: Is it fetching data from some source?

Comment: It essentially works as a link webpart except it does have a div layer over it to display the 4 most recent news updates. So, when editing the webpart from the page, the only data you need to enter is the link to the list.

Comment: I added a snippet of the div layer code above.

Comment: Please check your ULS logs using the correlation id you received with the error. The log should have a call stack which can tell you where in your code is it really failing.